# How to run "sysprep /generalize” in Azure Windows Virtual Machine (VM) from my local machine using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting, azure-vm

I have a windows Azure VM and need to execute “%windir%\system32\sysprep” and then execute “sysprep /generalize” both from admin mode from my local machine through Powershell. How can I do that ?

Comment: Any updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, as I know you can use a PowerShell script to achieve it. First, you can take a look at the [Sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep-command-line-options), it can be run in a PowerShell command `C:\WINDOWS\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /shutdown /oobe`. Put this command inside a script, then you can use two ways to run this script in the VM from your local machine. One is that use the Invoke command.

In Azure CLI:

```
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript -g group_name -n vm_name --scripts @script.ps1
```

In PowerShell:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -VMName 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'sample.ps1'
```

Another is that use the VM extension. It's a little complex. You can take a look at the Azure PowerShell command [`Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-4.1.0).

Output after running:-

```
Value[0]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : 
Value[1]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : 
Status          : Succeeded
Capacity        : 0
Count           : 0
```

Comment: Hey Charles, sorry for the late update. I was able to execute it successfully, I have updated my output in your answer, is it the supposed and right output ? Can you confirm ?

Comment: @Chaitanya Of course yes. Well, if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @CharlesXu, I can run any other scripts with Invoke-AzVMRunCommand , but Sysprep doesn't seem work. it got the same output as yours, but the VM was not shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I could't make sysprep work with Invoke-AzVMRunCommand, It run with succeeded status, but the VM was not shutdown.

Finally found https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/devops-sysprep-public-agents/1375989 and it make sense.

So just use Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to run sysprep won't work, I am thinking to reset a local admin user password and run the process as local admin might be a workaround.